# JList in JScrollPane drawing issue

Tags: java, jframe, jscrollpane, jlist, repaint

I have an issue in my Java application where putting a JList inside a JScrollPane seems to disrupt the first drawing of the list items.

I have a list being populated with items

```
public void populateFormulaList(Iterator<String> iter)
{
    list.setModel(new DefaultListModel<String>());
    DefaultListModel<String> listModel = (DefaultListModel<String>) list.getModel();
    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        listModel.addElement(iter.next());
    }       
}
```

And the component initialization looks like this

```
list = new JList<String>();
list.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

listPanel = new JScrollPane(list);
listPanel.setBounds(0, 40, 375, 550);

add(listPanel);
```

My problem is that when the application first runs, the list is populated with items, which I've debugged within eclipse and know the items exist within the JLists model, but if the JList is in the JScrollPane the items do not show the first time around. If I force the items to be repopulated the list shows all the items as expected.

I've tried using repaint() and revalidate() on the scrollpane, JList and their containing frame.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shoud never have to invoke methods like revalidate() and repaint() , when you change the model. It is the job of the model to notify the view when the data changes. So I would say your model has not been added to the view if the view is not painting itself. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.  Also, don't use setBounds(...). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: Is (`listPanel  instanceof JScrollPane`)  ?

Comment: listPanel is an instance of JScrollPane yes, sorry I could have included that.
The list contains all the elements added to it the first time around, it can be seen in the debugging mode of eclipse, it just doesn't show them. If the method is invoked again later in the application it renders fine. I will eventually alter the layouts to remove the setBounds

Comment: Where do you call `populateFormulaList()`? This might be a threading issue, do you properly use the event thread? `populateFormulaList` is inefficient, you might want to first populate the model, then set the model to the list.

Comment: Thanks Christian, that one solved it